# Android App Widget Not Updating After Second Screen On

Tags: android, kotlin, timer, widget

Good day. So I have small currency exchange widget. The widget MUST have always running Count Down timer. I really don't care if the timer won't update the view when screen is off so I never update widget, but when screen is on I do update it. 
The issue is that if I make screen go off and on 2 times, after second time the count down timer will simply run but the UI will never update,it will always remain on the last value it was before turning screen off and I can state by debugging that the update widget is fired and countdown timer is working. I have no clue what kind of good bugs Google put there but does anyone can help me with this?

Here is my simple code:

```
 if (timestamp.isNotEmpty()) {
                if (countDownTimer != null) {
                    countDownTimer?.cancel()
                    countDownTimer = null
                }
                val difference = DateUtils.getDifference(timestamp)

                countDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(difference, 1000) {
                    override fun onFinish() {
                        viewModel.getPrice()
                    }

                    override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                        val (minutesLeft, secsLeft) =
                            DateUtils.getMinAndSecsLeft(millisUntilFinished)
                        views.setTextViewText(
                            com.example.bipexchange.R.id.countDownTV,
                            context.getString(
                                com.example.bipexchange.R.string.minutesSeconds,
                                minutesLeft,
                                secsLeft
                            )
                        )

                        val pm = getSystemService(context, PowerManager::class.java)
                        val isScreenOn = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
                            pm?.isInteractive
                        } else {
                            pm?.isScreenOn
                        }
                        if (isScreenOn == true) {
                            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
                        }

                    }

                }
                countDownTimer?.start()
            }
```

Comment: maybe try skipping isScreenOn check? (maybe it returns false when screen is turned on the second time? if thats the case, try a different code, device or android version)

Comment: tried, same thing, tried on emualtor- same, tried on s9+ - same

Comment: Is isScreenOn returns false the second time? try a toast

Comment: isScreenOn works flawlessly, always returns true if user has screen on and false otherwis, debugged checked

Comment: I have inspected new thing, seems not related to the screen on/off, whenever activity destroys, view won't get updated any longer

Comment: That although happens on real device, on emulator if I quit activity the view won't get updated